# How to create a shell script that can scan a file for a specific word?

Tags: linux

one of the questions that I have been given to do for my Computer Science GCSE was:

Write a shell script that takes a string input from a user, asks for a file name and reports whether that string is present in the file.

However way I try to do it, I cannot create a shell script.
I don't need you to tell me the whole number, however, I have no idea where to start. I input the variable and the file name, however, I have no idea how to search for the chosen word in the chosen file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using grep can get this working, for example

```
viewEntry()
{
    echo "Entering view entry"
    echo -n "Enter Name: "
    read input
    if grep -q "$input" datafile
    then
        echo ""
        echo -n "Information -> "
        grep -w "$input" datafile
        echo ""
    else
        echo "/!\Name Not Found/!\\"
    fi
    echo "Exiting view entry"
    echo ""
}
```

dataFile is the file you would be reading from. Then making use of -q and -w arguments of grep, you should be able to navigate your chosen file.

This site does a great job explaining grep and your exact problem: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/

Answer (score 0):

The following shell-script is a very quick approach to do what you suggested:

```
#!/bin/sh                            # Tell your shell with what program this script should be exectued
echo "Please enter the filename: "
read filename                        # read user input into variable filename
count=`grep -c $1 $filename`         # store result of grep into variable count
if [ $count -gt 0 ]                  # check if count is greater than 0
then
  echo "String is present:" $1 
else
  echo "String not found:" $1
fi
```

You should look at [some tutorials](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/) to get the basics of shell-scripting. Your task isn't very complex, so after some reading you should be able understand what the script does and modify it according your needs.